# Standard Deviation and Monotonicity property

Tags: risk, variance, standard-deviation, coherent-risk-measure

I just read that standard deviation is a coherent risk measure, and therefore it should satisfy the monotonicity property:

$X_1 \geq X_2 \implies \rho(X_1) \leq \rho(X_2)$ where $X_1,X_2$ are asset positions.

We could define $X_1$ being greater than $X_2$ for every $\omega \in \Omega$, but $X_1$ could still have a greater standard deviation than $X_2$. Am I missing something with the definition of monotonicity?

Comment: Precisely because of that it is not a coherent risk measure.

Comment: @fes what is the problem with monotonicity proof at https://www.sfu.ca/~poitras/standard-deviation-coherent.pdf for example?

Comment: The fact that the standard deviation the difference of the two variables is positive does not make the measure monotonic.